# MySQL: SELECT if next row is not as what is expected

Tags: mysql

So I have a log table. Rows are basically like this:

```
id  function
n   init()
n+1 check()
n+2 done()
... repeat
```

But there are problems when it's like this:

```
id  function
n   init()
n+1 check()
n+2 done()
n+3 check() <-- should be init!
n+4 done()
```

How do I find rows that happen only in init->check->done->check->done contagious order? Basically after row done() it must be check() again in order to be SELECTed.

Is there a way to do this in 1 (or minimal) query? *Performance is not an issue.*

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?  My curiosity is if your ID column resets, or is an auto_increment...

Comment: It is auto_increment and the sample I gave is pretty much it. It's very simple log, I've only omitted timestamps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 SELECT line2.*
   FROM log line2
        JOIN log line1
        ON line2.id = line1.id + 1
  WHERE line1.function = 'done()'
    AND line2.function = 'check()'
```

I know you said performance wasn't an issue, but still ;)

Comment: Nice... somehow I confined myself to thinking in terms of 1 SELECT (without joins) only. I thought you can do something like regex lookahead. =P

Comment: @SyaZ there's nothing wrong with joins, really, they are there to be usefull, not avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
SELECT l.*
   FROM LOG l
  WHERE l.function = 'check()'
      AND EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                           FROM LOG t
                          WHERE t.function = 'done()'
                               AND t.id = l.id-1)
```

...to get the check() row which comes after a done(), and apparenly should be "init()" instead.

Comment: Thank you, first time I've seen SELECT NULL used.